# How to make use of multi cores on a single node of supercomputer 'Stampede'

Tags: parallelization

I am using Mathematica 10.4 in GUI mode on stampede supercomputer. I am using a single node on this machine and each node has two 8 core chips. Whenever I try to parallelize my code on 16 cores(using only one node) by launching kernels, it does not allow me and continue to compute the solution on a single core. The $ProcessorCount command showed me that there is only one processor. If on each node there are two 8 core chips that it should show me 8 or 16. I cannot figure out a way to connect all cores on one node. If anyone knows about it, please let me know asap. Thanks ashu

Comment: Have you tried `LaunchKernels[16]` in a new Mathematica session and seeing if you get 16 concurrent processes? Mathematica parallelizes simply by launching processes and depends on the operating system to distribute those processes to cores appropriately.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I didn't work.